# ObjectBox crash - java.lang.IllegalStateException ToOne object is null

Tags: objectbox

I've got 2 objects with the parent holding a list of children:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Backlink
    public ToMany<Child> children;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    ToOne<Parent> parent;
    ...
}
```

Then I call size() on the ToMany

```
parent.children.size()
```

And I get the following crash which I can't understand:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
ToOne object is null inside ...Child
io.objectbox.Cursor.nativeGetBacklinkEntities (Cursor.java)
io.objectbox.Cursor.getBacklinkEntities (Cursor.java:279)
io.objectbox.Box.internalGetBacklinkEntities (Box.java:623)
io.objectbox.relation.ToMany.ensureEntities (ToMany.java:172)
io.objectbox.relation.ToMany.size (ToMany.java:395)
```

It looks like the parent is looking at the list of children and for each one checks the link to the parent. It crashes because this link is null.
I don't understand how ObjectBox would manage to get to such a situation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe its because you didn't write the **No-arg constructor**.
So the to-one and to-many relations will not be automatically initialized by gradle.

As the crash said

```
ToOne object is null inside ...
```